# react-widget component not being properly rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the [react-widget](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/) and I'm facing the following issue:

### Expected:

See the default ReactWidget component.
[image: DropdownList]

### Actual:

The component does not load the styles.
[image: DropdownList]

It can be reproduced here:
[image: Edit 3q2myy7k25]

I've tried different lib versions for react and react-widget and the result was the same.
I'm missing something? Do I need to define at the *[DropdownList](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DropdownList)* the *[itemComponent](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DropdownList/#itemComponent)* prop or by default it should give me the expected result?

Comment: Keep in mind CodeSandbox is very tedious when doing imports into style files. So if you add the `import "react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css";` to the style.css file it might not work in the CodeSandbox editor. But from experience using react-widgets, yes you do need to include the css in your styles file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to import the CSS that comes with the `react-widget` library to give it its styling.

```
import "react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css";
```

Comment: `ERROR in ./~/react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css
Module parse failed: F:\projects\React\handallo- Shop\Shop\node_modules\react-widgets\dist\css\react-widgets.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. `                                                                                    throw this error how can i fix it

Answer (score 4):

Import the stylesheet like this:

```
import "react-widgets/styles.css";
```

Comment: Worked with Typescript